# Accurate way for finding Speed of a moving vehicle using android other than location.getspeed()

Tags: android, android-gps

In Android to calculate the speed of a moving car, have tried using location.getspeed() but failed to get good accuracy rate.
is there any other way to find speed using two location points.
in such a way that it will be having good accuracy rate?

Comment: The problem with getSpeed is that you don't know what its relative to.  But a lot of this also depends on what you want.  Speed is just distance/time, so if you want the speed you traveled between 2 points and you have the time you were at them you can just divide-  but that depends on you traveling a straight line.  If you're looking for speed over anything with turns, you're going to have to accurately figure out the distance actually traveled, which is non-trivial.

Comment: @GabeSechan `GPX` is accurate... but without recording, there are no values. calculating it perfectly in-sync with the current speed might not even be possible, because of the requirement to measure laps, somehow.